# Is it possible send command line digital code directly to LIRC socket for test purpose

Tags: linux, lirc

I have an small Linux tvbox with working remote control (LIRC). The socket (/run/lirc/lircd) is respond everything works like a charm. If I run irw command I get button code etc...
My question: Is it possible to prepare some Linux command which simulate like I pushed the physical remote button (simulate key press events programmatically)?
Maybe I should use lircd SOCKET COMMAND INTERFACE, any example?
Thank you for your time any feedback welcome!